# What is the proper way to handling OnClick ButtonView and other View in RecyclerView with touch listener?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, ontouchlistener

I have problem on Handling OnClick ButtonView and other View in RecyclerView Staggered Grid with OnTouch.

This my item RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <com.kamardagang.utils.SelectableRoundedImageView
            android:id="@+id/newsAvatar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_user" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_action"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and this Adapter with Handling Click:

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.ViewHolder> implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private Activity activity;
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataNews;
    private OnNewsItemClickListener OnNewsItemClickListener;

    public void setOnNewsItemClickListener(OnNewsItemClickListener onNewsItemClickListener) {
        this.OnNewsItemClickListener = onNewsItemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        final int viewId = v.getId();
        if (viewId == R.id.root_parent) {
            if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                if (OnNewsItemClickListener != null) {
                    OnNewsItemClickListener.onRootClick(v, (Integer) v.getTag());
                }
                return true;
            }

        } else if (viewId == R.id.btn_action) {
            if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                if (OnNewsItemClickListener != null) {
                    OnNewsItemClickListener.onActionClick(v, (Integer) v.getTag());
                }
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public interface OnNewsItemClickListener {
        public void onActionClick(View v, int position);

        public void onRootClick(View v, int position);
    }

    public NewsAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> News) {
        this.activity = activity;
        dataNews = News;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(activity, new SingleTapConfirm());
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @Bind(R.id.root_parent)
        CardView root_parent;
        @Bind(R.id.btn_action)
        Button btn_action;

        public ViewHolder(View vi) {
            super(vi);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, vi);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public NewsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                     int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.pin_item_news_recyclerview, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(v);
        holder.root_parent.setOnTouchListener(this);
        holder.btn_action.setOnTouchListener(this);
        return holder;
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            holder.root_parent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.btn_action.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.root_parent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.btn_action.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataNews.size();
    }

    public void delete_all() {
        int count = getItemCount();
        if (count > 0) {
            dataNews.clear();
        }
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private class SingleTapConfirm extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem : the Click of R.id.btn_action can detected , but not R.id.root_parent , so how to fix it ?

Comment: Try using viewHolder.itemview.setOnClickListener( ) to set the listener for the entire view instead of root_parent.

Answer (score 0):

to handle `recyclerView` click i have rather go with an `interface` that can talk with the `adapter` and my `activity`, for example you could do something like this:

```
public interface OnRecyclerItemClickListener {

    void onItemClickListener(View v, int position);

   // void onItemLongClickListener(View v, int position);

}
```

make your `activity` `implements` `OnRecyclerItemClickListener` and pass it to the constructor of you adapter and call its method whenever your `button` clicked. and do me a favorite, remove this

```
    holder.root_parent.setOnTouchListener(this);
    holder.btn_action.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

and add them inside `onBindViewHolder`

**EDIT:**

```
OnRecyclerItemClickListener onItemClick

public NewsAdapter(OnRecyclerItemClickListener onItemClick, /* my list */){
this.onItemClick = onItemClick;
}

public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
holder.myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickLisenter(){
    public void onClick(View v){
    onItemClick.onItemClickListener(v,position);
    }
});
}
```

this is just a sketch.

Comment: ok i understand this method, looks cleaner.im usining this in my project (gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {) -- how do you pick up what button was clicked and then do some action on that because after that i have (public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {) but that just picks up the item click or can i add something inside to pick up what button was clicked